# Как доделать вспывающее меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В блоках такое меню

```
<div class="track-button icon-angle-down">меню</div>

<div class="shortplaypanel">
   <div class="play_list">
      <a href="#">Играть</a> 
   </div>
   <div class="play_listdown">
      <a href="/engine/download.php">скачать</a>
   </div>
   <div class="play_down">
      <a href="{full-link}">Подробнее</a>
   </div>  
</div>
```

и JS

```
$('.track-button, .shortplaypanel').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings('.shortplaypanel').fadeIn();
});
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.shortplaypanel').fadeOut();
});
```

Не получается добиться того чтобы:
Когда нажимаешь на второе меню, первое исчезало и если нажмешь в любую часть страницы, тоже чтоб исчезало.
Нужно ещё не использовать метод `e.stopPropagation();` перестаёт воспроизведение работать. 
Пример [http://codepen.io/](http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/YwOPoJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
   if ($(event.target).is('.track-button')) return;
     $('.shortplaypanel').fadeOut();      
     });


$('.track-button').click(function () {
  $('.shortplaypanel').not($(this)).fadeOut();
  $(this).siblings('.shortplaypanel').toggle();
});
```

Comment: При повторном нажатии не закрывается и на body тоже и надо как-то без этого `e.stopPropagation();` а то плеер не работает.

Comment: @Сергей Лапшин нынче должно работать. Я проверял только с одним классом у элемента, у вас пара, может надо что-то поправить

Comment: А `toggle` плавный ни как не сделать?

Comment: у него параметр - время. поставьте большое, будет медленно

Answer (score 0):

вот тебе рабочий скрипт, как я и писал ранее, в логическом примере....

```
        $('.wrap').find('.track-button').click(function(){
            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');//Expand or collapse this blocks
            $(".shortplaypanel").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');//Hide the other blocks
        });
```

работает в слайде, на фейд переделать  надеюсь сможеш !

Comment: Так вообще ничего не работает

Comment: это логический набросок, вот рабочий пример(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154549/jquery-show-hide-siblings) похожий.

Comment: Там всё по другому

Comment: переделал,все работает, даже если нажать на ту-же "меню", он скроет только нужный блок....  !