# Как закрыть блок при клике вне него?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть три блока, каждый из которых открывается при клике на кнопку.

```
$('.language_page span').click(function() {
        if ($(".languages_page_list").css("display") != "block") {
            $(".languages_page_list").fadeIn(300);
            var lpl_open = true;
            $(document).click(function(event) {
                if (!lpl_open && $(event.target).closest(".languages_page_list").length == 0) {
                    $(".languages_page_list").fadeOut(300);
                }
                var lpl_open = false;
            });
        } else {
            $(".languages_page_list").fadeOut(300); 
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Если просто копирую код отдельно для трёх блоков, но только если кликать вне блоков. А если открыт блок 1, и я кликаю на кнопку для открытия блока 2, то блок 2 открывается, но первый закрываться не хочет. Далее, если кликнуть вне блоков, то они оба закроются. Как можно поправить скрипт, чтобы всё работало правильно?

Comment: плохая практика назначать клик в клике и проверять css, добавьте минимальный html и css

Comment: Вот пример, как работает сейчас: http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/abc/test.html

Comment: Окошки закрываются только при клике вне области окон и вне кнопок. И также при клике на кнопку закрывается окно, открытое этой кнопкой. Должно закрываться сразу 3 окна, так как по идее мы вне окна кликаем, хоть и на кнопку.

Comment: гляньте тут, очень похоже http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488753/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E/488758#488758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял всё по ссылке, стили не трогал. https://jsfiddle.net/vm54k7g4/

html

```
<div class="button button1" data-for="w1">Кнопка 1</div>
<div class="button button2" data-for="w2">Кнопка 2</div>
<div class="button button3" data-for="w3">Кнопка 3</div>

<div class="window window1" id="w1" style="display: none;">Текст 1</div>
<div class="window window2" id="w2" style="display: none;">Текст 2</div>
<div class="window window3" id="w3" style="display: none;">Текст 3</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click','.button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var toggler = $(this),
          targetWindow = $( '#' + toggler.data('for') ),
          targetWindowId = targetWindow.attr('id'),
          targetWindowDisplayed = ( targetWindow.css("display") == "block" );


      if ( !targetWindowDisplayed ) {            
          targetWindow.stop().fadeIn(300);
      }

      $(document).off('click.windowouter'+targetWindowId).on('click.windowouter'+targetWindowId,function(e){
          var clickTarget = $(e.target),
              allChilds = $(targetWindow).find('*');
          if ( $(e.target).is(toggler) ) {/*клик по кнопке*/
              $(document).off('click.windowouter'+targetWindowId);
              targetWindow.stop().fadeOut(300);
          }
          else if ( $(e.target).is(targetWindow) || $(e.target).is(allChilds) ) {/*клик по окошку*/}            
          else {// ...кликаутсайд
              $(document).off('click.windowouter'+targetWindowId);
              targetWindow.stop().fadeOut(300);
          }
      });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял то так:

```js
$(function(){
    $('div button').click(function(){
        var pole = $(this).attr('id'); //получаем идентификатор блока для отображения
      
      $(".pole-1, .pole-2, .pole-3").hide(); //скрываем все блоки с текстом
        
        $('.'+ pole).fadeIn(300); // показываем нужный блок
    });
});
```

```css
.pole-1 {
  display: none;
  }

.pole-2 {
  display: none;
  }

.pole-3 {
  display: none;
  }

#parent {
  width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button id="pole-1">Включить поле 1</button>
  <div class="pole-1">поле 1</div>
  <button id="pole-2">Включить поле 2</button>
  <div class="pole-2">поле 1</div>
  <button id="pole-3">Включить поле 3</button>
  <div class="pole-3">поле 1</div>  
  </div>
```

В принципе вариантов может быть много.

Comment: Нет, закрытие должно быть при клике и мимо сообщения, и мимо кнопки. А если нажимаем на кнопку, то должно происходить то, что у вас.

Answer (score 0):

замените классы на свои

```js
$(function() {
  var $but = $(".menu-main-item"),
    $blocks = $(".menu-mega");
  $but.each(function(i, elem) {
    var $el = $(elem);
    $el.click(function() {
      $but.not($el).removeClass("active-menu-item");
      $el.toggleClass("active-menu-item");
      $blocks.filter(function(j,
        el) {
        i == j && $(el).fadeToggle();
        return i != j
      }).hide();
    })
  });
  $('html').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.menu-main-item, .menu-mega').length) return;
    $but.filter('.active-menu-item').click()
  });
});
```

```css
.active-menu-item {
  background: #FFE4B5;
}
div.menu-mega {
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.menu-main-item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
#menu-restoran {
  background-color: green
}
#menu-trade {
  background-color: pink
}
#menu-equipment {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-main-nav">
  <li><a class="menu-main-item" href="#" data-item="menu-restoran">Для ресторанов<i class="main-choise"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="menu-main-item" href="#" data-item="menu-trade">Для торговли<i class="main-choise"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="menu-main-item" href="#" data-item="menu-equipment">Торговое оборудование<i class="main-choise"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="menu-mega" id="menu-restoran">
  test 1
</div>

<div class="menu-mega" id="menu-trade">
  test 2
</div>
<div class="menu-mega" id="menu-equipment">
  test 3
</div>
```